# SwiftUI how to get the coordinate in Sheet View(Modal View) [from .sheet(isPresented: )ViewModifier]

Tags: swiftui

I am using SwiftUI framework to construct the view, and use the .fullScreenCover and .sheet viewModifer to test the coordiate inside, I put a button inside the view and my question is:

1. the coordinate origin Y of the button inside the full screen cover view is 143, it is ok.
2. the coordinate origin Y of the button inside the sheet view is 165, more than 143, I guess it may be there is a space above the sheet view, and I get the coordiate using Geometry Reader proxy.frame in global, so it may be based on the device's cooridate space.
3. My target is how can I get the coordinate based on the sheet view, i.e. i wanna make the origin Y show 143 too in the sheet view.
   Note: I am testing it using iPhone 12 Pro simulator.

[This is the image link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvleG.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var showSheet = false
@State var ShowFullScreen = false
@State var origin: CGPoint?

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Button {
                showSheet = true
            } label: {
                Text("showSheet")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                NavigationView {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Button {
                            origin = proxy.frame(in: .global).origin
                        } label: {
                            Text("origin Y in Sheet: \(origin?.y.description ?? "nil")")
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    }
                    .toolbar {
                        Button {
                            showSheet = false
                            origin = nil
                        } label: {
                            Text("Dismiss")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button {
                ShowFullScreen = true
            } label: {
                Text("ShowFullScreen")
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $ShowFullScreen) {
                NavigationView {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Button {
                            origin = proxy.frame(in: .global).origin
                        } label: {
                            Text("origin Y in FullScreen: \(origin?.y.description ?? "nil")")
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    }
                    .toolbar {
                        Button {
                            ShowFullScreen = false
                            origin = nil
                        } label: {
                            Text("Dismiss")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No, it is because in full screen there safe-area inset at top, but in sheet it is absent.

Comment: @Asperi Do you know how to get the Sheet View based coordinate instead of global, so that the button inside the sheet view is not 165, it should be less than 165, may be 108 ( 165 - 47 top safe area  - 10 space above sheet).